# Hypothesis Testing in Python: One sample T Test without Standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, problem-solving, hypothesis-testing

**Update**

So the way I solved the question was through taking *one* sample of the weights array like so

```
sample = np.random.permutation(weights)
```

Then calculate the sample standard deviation

```
std = np.std(sample)
```

Finally plug it all in to the
[t score equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsrQw.png)

The result is 1.8742476583604653, which is used to find the p value in a t distribution table, leading to p ~= 0.075, which accepts the null hypothesis of the mean being 72.

---

I am brand new to Hypothesis testing and I want to know the correct way to answer this question

The question asks:

- If the weights are normally distributed
- Use a one sample t-test to test hypothesis that the mean is 72

**Significance level is 0.05**

First, you are given a set of weights

```
weights = [94.93428306,  82.23471398, 97.95377076, 115.46059713, 80.31693251,  80.31726086, 116.58425631, 
           100.34869458,  75.61051228, 95.85120087, 75.73164614, 75.68540493, 89.83924543,  46.73439511,  
           50.50164335,  73.75424942,  64.74337759,  91.28494665, 66.83951849, 56.75392597, 114.31297538, 
           80.48447399,  86.35056409,  56.50503628, 74.11234551,  66.1092259 ,  53.49006423,  68.75698018,
           58.9936131 ,  62.0830625 ,  58.98293388,  83.52278185, 64.86502775,  54.42289071,  73.22544912,  
           52.7915635 ,67.08863595,  45.40329876,  51.71813951,  66.96861236, 72.3846658 ,  66.71368281,  
           63.84351718,  61.98896304, 50.2147801 ,  57.80155792,  60.39361229,  75.57122226, 68.4361829 , 47.36959845]
```

Using the Shapiro Wiki test (from scipy library) to check if the results are normally distributed

- H0 = weights are normally distributed
- HA = weights are not normally distributed

```
form scipy import stats
shapiro = stats.shaprio(weights)

# ShapiroResult(statistic=0.9404902458190918, pvalue=0.014088480733335018)
```

So from what I understand, there is a 95% probability that the weights are not normally distributed.

This leads to the second issue. If the weights are not normally distributed, how can you use a one sample t test ?

My initital thought was to permutate the data and then sample it randomly like so

```
perm_repl_means =[]

for i in range(1000):
    weights_perm = np.random.permutation(weights)
    sample_a = weights_perm[:len(weights) //2]
    sample_b = weights_perm[len(weights)//2:]
    mean_diff = sample_a.mean()- sample_b.mean()
    perm_repl_means.append(mean_diff)
```

Then get the standard deviation

```
std = np.std(perm_repl_means)
Standard Deviation = 4.918230395520542
```

And from there try to use the equation

t = sample mean - population mean / (standard deviation / sqrt(sample size) )

But I get strange values like -50.41615468880369.
I know its incorrect because taking the mean of the weights array yields 71.9277206544

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong and how to correctly approach this question ?

Comment: If your data are not normally distributed, then this violate the hypothesis for the t-test. This might explain why you have weird results. Also, I do not really understand what you have done with your permuted data.

Comment: Thats what I thought as well, but I assumed there was something wrong since they are asking for a t test, as if it is supposed to be normally distributed. Also, the permutation function will just reorder the list , so I was taking smaller samples from that new set of data and trying to calculate the difference in means to get the mean of all the means. Like I said I am not entirely sure how to approach the problem so this was an attempt at that

Comment: Can you show a Q-Q plot of your data ? Some visual inspection can help to understand what is going on. Also, are you sure that your data should be normal ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/CADEP7s That is a plot of the original weights data

Comment: I assume the data has to be normally distributed in order to use a one sample t test.

Comment: If your sample size is "large enough" you can perform a one sample $t$ test for a population mean even if your population isn't normal. Elementary textbooks usually say $n\geq 30$ is good enough, so I think you're okay to proceed to part $(b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your data into R and did a Shapiro-**Wilk** test,
with the following results:

```
shapiro.test(weights)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  weights
W = 0.94049, p-value = 0.01409
```

The P-value $0.014$ indicates that the probability
a truly normal sample of size $n=50$ would give such
results is small. So it seems prudent not to use
the data in procedures that require normal data.

However, it is possible that an inconconsequential
quirk in your data could account for such a small
P-value. Many statisticians prefer to look at a Q-Q
plot of the data to judge randomness. Data points in
a Q-Q plot of normal data should be roughly linear
(except perhaps for relatively few points in the tails).

Here is a Q-Q plot of your weight data made using R. It is not satisfactorily
linear.

```
qqnorm(weights)
 qqline(weights, col="blue")
```

[image]

Even a histogram of the weights shows marked skewness
toward the right.

```
hist(weights, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

I don't know what kind of t test you have in mind.
There is some controversy about using t tests with
sample sizes as large as $n = 50,$ with non-normal
data. I would not trust results of a t test from
such a markedly skewed distribution.

The 'rule'
in some elementary texts that normality does not
matter in t tests with sample sizes above thirty
is clearly wrong for strongly skewed data. In particular,
the numerator and denominator of the t statistic
are not independent for such non-normal data, so the
so-called 't statistic' does not have a t distribution.

*Addendum per Comment:* A 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI
for the mean $\mu$ of population weights is $(67.0,76.7).$

```
set.seed(2022)
a.obs = mean(weights);  a.obs
[1] 71.92772
d = replicate(2000, mean(sample(weights,50,rep=T))-a.obs)
UL = quantile(d, c(.975,.025))
a.obs - UL
   97.5%     2.5% 
66.97763 76.72769
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is why I don't really understand the question being asked. I am not sure how to test the data after knowing its not normally distributed. Unless there is another way to test for the mean ?

Comment: If you could say exactly what test you want to do and why, you might get suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately, everything I wrote is the entire scope of the question. Basically just to find a way to test the hypothesis that the mean of the data is 72

Comment: One style of 95% non-parametric bootstrap CI for the population mean weight is shown in an addendum to my answer. It includes 72, so data seem consistent with μ=72. // You might check to see if your book is one of those that is willing to use t methods indiscriminately for n>30, you will find that that a t test does not reject $H_0:μ=72$ in favor of the 2-sided alternative. Then you might just (compliantly, quoting book) use the t test for this exercise, and make a mental note never to do that in a real application--where someone's life, safety, or reputation might be affected.